# Expected primary-expression before various tokens

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

The following code:

```
class queuenode {
public:
    queuenode();
    queuenode(cargo *mydata);
    ~queuenode() {delete cargo;} //Queuenodes delete their cargo on destruction - note that queuenodes DON'T free their neighbour, that's up to the queue class
public:
    queuenode *next;
    int pri; //this should always be equal to our cargo's pri
    cargo *data;
};

queuenode::queuenode(void) {
    next= (queuenode *) NULL; 
    cargo = (cargo *) NULL; //default const creates a null queuenode - pri is left undefined
}

queuenode::queuenode(cargo *mydata) {
    //Convert constr creates a queuenode wrapping a cargo, also setting pri to its pri
    data=mydata; 
    pri=mydata->pri; 
    next=(queuenode *) NULL;
}
```

gives me the following errors:

> ```
> pq_linkedlist.cpp: In destructor 'queuenode::~queuenode()':
> pq_linkedlist.cpp:19:28: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token
> pq_linkedlist.cpp: In constructor 'queuenode::queuenode()':
> pq_linkedlist.cpp:28:8: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
> ```

I have no idea what's happening or why. There's all sorts of people with the same error message on the internet but all their problems seem to have to do with extra semicolons, and I'm pretty sure I don't have any.

Comment: Replace NULL with nullptr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
~queuenode() {delete cargo;}
```

Should be:

```
~queuenode() {delete data;}
```

`cargo` is the type, `data` is the variable. Saying `delete cargo` makes as much sense as saying `delete int`.

Similarly this line is wrong:

```
cargo = (cargo *) NULL;
```

Comment: For posterity's sake, would you mind explaining what the error actually means and how it applies to this situation? I only ask 'cos it seems a bit silly that there's so many "just do this to fix it" answers out there and none that actually explain how you could work out what was wrong from the error message.

Comment: @Schilcote Compilers work by incrementally parsing the source file. What happens here is that the compiler just saw the keyword `delete`. This means that the compiler expects an expression (`primary-expression`) to come next. Instead it found a type, `cargo`. Types can be part of an expression, for example `int(5)` is an expression, so the compiler keeps looking, but then it finds a `;`. `cargo` is not an expression, so the compiler complains that it didn't find an expression before it found `;`, which is the exact error you got.